# Android crop image like camscanner

Tags: android, image, draw, crop

I am developing a project which requires the image crop feature like camscanner android application,when a picture is taken and when user clicks the crop button, a rectangle overlay should be shown as in camscanner. Where the rectangle path can be stretched to any angle and can perform crop.please do help me with a solution.

I was referring to https://github.com/edmodo/cropper . but this as only rectangle overlay with 4 points.please do help me if any one has a link or solution!!

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform Auto crop for document Recognize image using camera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679768/how-to-perform-auto-crop-for-document-recognize-image-using-camera)

Answer (score 43):

I had a similar requirement and I too didn't find any concrete solution similar to CamScanner, so I have taken the challenge and have implemented a scan library (on top of OpenCV, rich image processing library) similar to CamScanner which can be easily integrated into an existing application, using the library you will be able to select the exact edges in whatever angle and crop the document accordingly from the selected 4 edges and change the perspective transformation of the cropped image.

Github link of the Android ScanLibrary: https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo

[image]

Comment: in crop fragment polygon surface is not automatically detecting edges can you help me in fixing this

Comment: @jhansi am using the sam scan library but one small problem is that the rectangle croping is not detecting the full image it detecting from the half the image but when its cropped am getting the full image but if I adjust the rectangle to the edges of the document am getting the half the image, do u have any idea on it, If u need i can post the image for your reference

Comment: @Balaji which scan library are you using? Is that been forked from my AndroidScannerDemo repo?

Comment: @jhansi nice library you have made. Can you please provide me some link for how can i use OpenCV into my project, any tutorial or reference material

Comment: @jhansi, there are libpng issues for that reason google rejeted the application ,How to solve this issues ?

Comment: @suman, as you know we have upgraded the openCV to 3.1 which have resolved the libpng issues.

Comment: The main problem of this library is the image orientation is always 90 degree rotated. 2nd problem is, it lacks auto edge detection.

Comment: This is the best free open source library there is for this kind of thing. Thank you for contributing

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for this. BTW, does anyone know a similar library that works on iOS?

Comment: is there any way to implement zoom crop magnify lens feature similar to cam scanner ?

Comment: @Raptor It does have auto-edge detection although not so robust and the images just worked fine for me, moreover rotating bitmaps is just three lines of code

Comment: i am using this library in my project but after clicking image nothing happens ...crop part is not coming. here is my code https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pKTq0QwxuN1jy9Q1eFSQyr-TUEHFKHtQ can you please help me

Comment: @jhansi does this work while capturing the images from camera or only after capturing the images?

Comment: @jhansi you mean while capturing the image the cropper will be displayed on the top of the screen and once i click the image only the part of the screen inside that cropper  will be clicked?

Comment: No @CosmicDev, after you capture the picture you can crop it.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @jhansi for this amazing library but the problem of this library([Android Scanner Library](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo)) is the image orientation is always 90 degree rotated, we can solve it like this.

**Solution in Kotlin**

In OnActivityResult it gives you bitmap and this bitmap you can pass to "Bitmap.roate" method.

Use it like this:   `val rotatedBitmap=bitmap.rotate(90f)`
`imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap)`

Paste this method in your activity: 
`fun Bitmap.rotate(degrees: Float): Bitmap {
        val matrix = Matrix().apply { postRotate(degrees) }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(this, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
    }`