# Document polygon detection and cropping in Android

Tags: android, opencv, firebase-mlkit

I need to create a functionality similar to one that [CamScanner app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner) offers. I have searched the net for days and the best matches that I found were the following:

1. [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923569/android-crop-image-like-camscanner) where a outdated library is suggested, it seems to be best so far, but it is old, it does not auto detect edges of the document
2. [This Library](https://github.com/pqpo/SmartCropper) which seems to autodetect the document but then it damages the quality of the cropped image. this one is also outdated..

I found and tested a lot more libraries like this, but all of them seems to be outdated, most of them does not detect edges of the document and work very bad.

I searched a lot to find out if I can use Android's ML Kit for solving this problem, but didn't find any answer on that topic as well.

So I feel quite lost on what direction to go on and where to start from. Do you have any suggestions?
Are there any known libraries which do this?
Is it possible to do this with ML Kit?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with ML Kit yet, but have it high on our backlog to tackle. I am personally not aware of anything you can pick off-the-shelf, but there might be commercial SDKs that offer this. Some companies have trained their own models, e.g. [WPS Document Image Dewarping](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/12/kingsoft-wps-document-image-dewarping.html).

Comment: Just found your answer looking for a MLKit based solution. I'm curious - is it still high on your backlog because it still doesn't seem to be implemented yet?